# Opacity in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am creating a vexel portrait in Illustrator. For the shading areas I am using a 5% opacity for each shape that I draw w/ the pen tool. But I find that I have to set the opacity back to 5% for each shape that I draw. How can I avoid doing this and just 5% opacity for all of the shapes. Note: I don't want to set 5% opacity for shapes I have drawn, but the shapes that I am going to draw. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make certain "New Art Has Basic Appearance" is **not** checked in the Appearance Panel menu.

[image: Appearance Panel]

This will allow newly drawn objects to retain appearance settings as you draw.